# MVVM - IsEnabled not working properly with bound boolean

Tags: c#, wpf, button, mvvm, isenabled

I have a simple button:

```
<Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding StartAction}" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=Loading, Converter={StaticResource InverseBooleanConverter}}"/>
```

As you can see, IsEnabled is bound to a boolean property. When StartAction is executed, the boolean is set on true so the button gets disabled (note that I'm using a InverseBooleanConverter). This works fine.

After changing the boolean, the StartAction-method creates a new thread which calls a callback on the ViewModel (where the thread was created, so where the StartAction-method can be found) when it's finished. This callback is very simple:

```
private void DisplayResult()
{
    Loading = false;
}
```

This should enable the button again, however, this doesn't happen.

If I set loading on false somewhere else, the button DOES get enabled. Together with the button, some other elements (also bound to this boolean) should get invisible/visible when the boolean changes and that DOES work fine too, even when the Loading property is changed by the callback method.

I'm a bit confused here. Why doesn't it work? I think it may have something to do with the thread, but I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work, especially since it works with other elements on the UI.

Just to be clear, this is the Loading property:

```
public bool Loading
{
    get { return loading; }
    set
    {
        if (loading != value)
        {
            loading = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Loading");
        }
    }
}
```

Any idea what might be wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: have you traced it through the converter?

Comment: Yes, nothing seems to be wrong with the converter.

Comment: Maybe there is a problem with the `StartAction` command `CanExecute`? Can you post the code of `StartAction`?

Comment: And you must have an IPropertyChange* whatever it's called that you're inheriting from. Seems right otherwise. Threads?

Comment: Have you tried changing Loading to a dependency property and see if it solves your problem?

Comment: You do know, that IsEnabled is modified indirectly through the command? If its canExecute is false, the button appears to be disabled, but the IsEnabled is not changed(my guess is to stop changing it with tools like snoop and breaking an application).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your callback you may need to instruct the UI to check that property again and update accordingly. This is performed with the `CommandManager`. I've added a bit to your callback code:

```
private void DisplayResult()
{
    Loading = false;
    CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
}
```

The [`CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandmanager.invalidaterequerysuggested.aspx) instructs WPF to update any bound controls as necessary right away.